# How to insert an object in CoreData with toMany relationship? Swift3/Xcode8

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, relational-database, one-to-many

I created a database CoreData for my application but I am having a tremendous doubt as to how to insert a new related object

[image: My DB here]

My question is, how to insert new courses for existing students? Here is the snippet of code:

```
func salvarCursos(codCursoSV: String, desCursoSV: String, loginAlunoSV: String){

let contexto = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let curso = Cursos(context: contexto)

curso.codcurso = codCursoSV
curso.descurso = desCursoSV
curso.login = loginAlunoSV
//curso.loginAlunos = ???

(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
}
```

I can insert an object but I do not know how to make this relationship for items that already exist in other tables. 
I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to fetch the objects from table and then associate the related objects to the fetched objects and then save the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending if your relationship is marked as ordered or not, you create a `NSOrderedSet` or a `NSSet` of objects you fetched before using a fetch request and assign them to a property.